# Need some clarification to understand an inequality involving exponential sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

I was looking into Montgomery's proof of the large sieve inequality in his book on [Topics in Multiplicative Number Theory](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0060851.pdf?pdf=button), and on page $18$, we have
$$B(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}b_ke(kx),$$ for $x\in\mathcal{X}$ where $\mathcal{X}\subset(0,1]$, $e(x)=\exp(2\pi ix)$, and
$$b_k=\begin{cases}1 & \text{for } |k|\leq K\\
                        1-\frac{|k|-K}{A} & \text{for } K\leq|k|\leq K+A\\
                        0 & \text{for } |k|>K+A\end{cases}$$
and $A>0$ is a constant. Then, we obtain
$$B(x)=\frac{(\sin(K+A)\pi x)^2-(\sin K\pi x)^2}{A(\sin\pi x)^2},$$ $B(0)=2K+A$, and $$B(x)\leq A^{-1}(\pi^{-2}||x||^{-2}+1)$$ for non-integral $x$. Then, it is written that
$$\sum\limits_{x^{\prime}\in\mathcal{X}}|B(x^{\prime}-x)|\leq B(0)+\frac{R}{A}+\frac{2}{A\pi^2}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\frac{R+1}{2}}||j\delta||^{-2},$$ where $||x^{\prime}-x||\ge\delta>0$ for any $x^{\prime},x\in\mathcal{X}$.

**Question:** Could someone explain to me how he is getting the $B(0)$ and the last summation in the inequality above? Specifically, why is the last summation in the form $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\frac{R+1}{2}}||j\delta||^{-2}$ and multiplied by $2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula for $B(0)$ comes from noting that $B(0) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty b_k$, and for positive integers $A,K$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty b_k &= b_0 + \sum_{0 < |k| \leq K} 1 + \sum_{K < |k| \leq K+A} \Big(1 - \frac{|k|-K}{A}\Big) \\
& = 1 + 2K + 2 \sum_{K < k \leq K+A} \Big(1 - \frac{k}{A} + \frac{K}{A} \Big) \\
&= 1 + 2K + 2(1+K/A) \sum_{K < k \leq K+A} 1 -\frac{2}{A} \sum_{K < k \leq K+A}k  \\
&= 1 + 2K + 2A + 2K - (2/A)(A/2)(2K+A+1) = 2K + A.
\end{align*}

To see the upper bound for $\sum_{x' \in \mathcal{X}} |B(x'-x)|$, label the elements of $\mathcal{X}$ as $x = x_0, \dots, x_{R-1}$, with $||x_k - x||$ ascending. Then, observe that since the points $x_k$ are $\delta$-spaced mod $1$, in the open interval $(-j\delta,j\delta)$ there can be at most $2j-1$ elements of $\mathcal{X}$; it follows that $|x_j - x | \geq \delta \lceil j/2 \rceil$ for $1 \leq j \leq R-1$. Since necessarily $\delta \leq 1/R$, this means that $||x_j-x|| \geq \delta \lceil j/2 \rceil$ for these $j$. Consequently, we have that
\begin{align*}
&\sum\limits_{x^{\prime}\in\mathcal{X}}|B(x^{\prime}-x)| \\
&\leq  \sum_{x'=x_0 = x} B(x'-x) + \sum_{j=1}^{R-1} \Big(\frac{1}{A} + \frac{1}{ A \pi^2} \frac{1}{||x_j-x||^2} \Big) \\
&\leq B(0) + \frac{R}{A} + \frac{1}{A \pi^2} \sum_{j=1}^R \frac{1}{\delta^2 \lceil j/2 \rceil^2} \\
&\leq B(0) + \frac{R}{A} + \frac{1}{A \pi^2 \delta^2} \sum_{j=1 \atop j \text{ even}}^R \frac{1}{\lceil j/2 \rceil^2} +  \frac{1}{A \pi^2 \delta^2} \sum_{j=1 \atop j \text{ odd}}^R \frac{1}{\lceil j/2 \rceil^2}  \\
&\leq B(0) + \frac{R}{A} + \frac{1}{A \pi^2 \delta^2} \sum_{1 \leq j \leq R/2} \frac{1}{\lceil 2j/2 \rceil^2} +  \frac{1}{A \pi^2 \delta^2} \sum_{1 \leq j \leq (R+1)/2} \frac{1}{\lceil (2j-1)/2 \rceil^2}  \\
&\leq B(0) + \frac{R}{A} + \frac{1}{A \pi^2\delta^2} \sum_{1 \leq j \leq R/2} \frac{1}{j^2} +  \frac{1}{A \pi^2 \delta^2} \sum_{1 \leq j \leq (R+1)/2} \frac{1}{j^2}  \\
&\leq B(0)+\frac{R}{A}+\frac{2}{A\pi^2 \delta^2}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\frac{R+1}{2}}(1/j^2) \leq B(0)+\frac{R}{A}+\frac{2}{A\pi^2 \delta^2}\zeta(2) .
\end{align*}